# How can I copy files from i directory to another using Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am new for Mule ESB. My requirement is every 15 mins interval specific files (pattern based) should be moved from one directory location to another. I have gone through with the tool and found a poll node, which is likely to be fired within a given timeinterval.

Can someone please provide me detail steps and wireflow diagram to achieve this. This will be really helpful for me. Please let me know if you need anymore details from my side.

Thanks in Advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify file connector and file endpoint([see file transport doc](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/File+Transport+Reference))

that's basically it

e.g.

```
 <file:connector name="readFileConnector" autoDelete="true" pollingFrequency="6000" fileAge="30000" streaming="false" />


<file:endpoint name="readFileEndpoint" connector-ref="readFileConnector" path="${transaction.in}" moveToDirectory="${transaction.backup}" moveToPattern="#[function:datestamp]-#[header:originalFilename]"/>

<flow name="readAndLog">
    <inbound-endpoint ref="readFileEndpoint"/>

    //possible processing if any

    <vm:outbound-endpoint ref="vmFileIn"/>
</flow>
```

some crucial points: 
autodelete - delete or not files on copy.
pollingFrequency - how often to check the directory for files to copy
path - from where to read files
moveToDirectory - where to put them

Comment: How many nodes will be used to perform this. Single File node is getting error out

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a quartz connector is much more flexible. Here's an example that you can use.

Conectors

```
<file:connector name="in" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<file:connector name="out" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
```

Flows

```
<flow name="stackoverflowFlow1" doc:name="stackoverflowFlow1">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz" jobName="test" repeatInterval="120000">
        <quartz:event-generator-job/>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>               
    <flow-ref name="stackoverflowFlow3" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>        
</flow>  
<flow name="stackoverflowFlow3" doc:name="stackoverflowFlow3">        
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:/stackoverflow/q-001/fuente" connector-ref="in" doc:name="File">
        <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.txt" />
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="listo" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="out" path="C:/stackoverflow/q-001/destino" doc:name="File"/>     
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the quartz connector beside the file connector for the specific pattern you can use the regex filter which is available in the file connector. or you can wrap the file connector in the poll scope and fix the fixed frequency scheduler or the cron jobs according to your time interval requirement.